# No subfolders shown for Nautilus bookmark folders. How can I navigate to them?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 22.04

Ubuntu 22.04
Nautilus, the default gnome file manager.
I have some bookmarks and they show on the left panel.
However, there are subdirectories that exist on the file system that do not show.
How can I navigate to them through these bookmarks?
Or how can I get those subfolders to show, like in regular file managers.

Comment: seems like a permissions issue, I might delete this queston...

Comment: update , Nautilus is fine, it is Firefox in saving. and o nly for the top Home, Documents , Downloads , but not  Pictures that when selected show no sub folders. same thing with Brave Browser. aha, Ive discovered that these save dialogs are sorted by name, and folders are not at the top. If I sort by type I can scroll down them  and find the folders. kind of daft this is. now, how to change it.

Answer (score 0):

wrong permission in that directory

> sudo chmod 755 /media/username/Books

then bookmark it again, works and subdirectories show in Nautilus when selecting the bookmark. Books being a partition with that label. username is of course my username

Answer (score 0):

not as simple as that, I am saving a pdf from a Firefox page , choosing Documents (which is a default Ubuntu install Bookmarked home folder), and no folders are shown their either. so the only way was to put the path in manually in the filename dialogue... it worked.

Comment: maybe I should just go to Linux from Scratch and command line only.