# Save dialog with Firefox and Brave Browser, folders are not at the top. How do I get them to show always at the top?

Tags: firefox, 22.04

a different question from the one I posed a while back, as I discovered  by sorting  by type that the folders are there, just not at the top  like normal save as dialogs.
[No subfolders shown for Nautilus bookmark folders. How can I navigate to them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1434377/no-subfolders-shown-for-nautilus-bookmark-folders-how-can-i-navigate-to-them)

so I go save as or save anything from the browser and the chooser dialogue, select Documents or Downloads and the sub folders are mixed in with sort by name and not at the top. But Pictures folder is normal with those subfolders at the top.

Answer (score 0):

click on sort column  by type to get the folders at the top then choose the subfolder. the names of the files, however , will not be in name order but by type then name.. so this does not give a 'normal' dialogue where folders are always at the top. the sorting selection for each folder will persist. that goes for any folders on the left side, and explains how my two folders got mucked  up, I must have sorted by name at one stage and it stayed that way.

Comment: noting the save dialogue is not the same as the Nautilus Files app, as far as I can tell.

Comment: noting too on a subsequent use of this dialogue, although the folders are at the top, they are not sorted in name order. another click of the type column is necessary to get them sorted into name order.